# CIFS slashes changed to backslashes after upgrade

Tags: linux, cifs, opensuse

I am working on linux server which does its backup via rsync to a cifs-mounted share on an external NAS (D-Link DNS-320). Everything worked fine on opensuse 11.4. After upgrade to opensuse 12.2, the backup script is still working, but files on the share are displayed strangely.
The share is mounted on /backup and the backups are in subfolders of directory /backup/daily. So, I would  `ls /backup` expect to show just the `daily` folder. However, it takes a long time and finally lists the files like this:

```
www:~ # ls /backup
daily
\daily
\daily\2012_week44
[...]
\daily\2012_week45\home\user\Maildir\cur\1351686611.2233_0.www:2,
\daily\2012_week45\home\user\Maildir\cur\1351696819.5035_0.www:2,
\daily\2012_week45\home\user\Maildir\cur\1351698486.5356_0.www:2,S
```

Week 44 is the time of the upgrade.

If I do `ls /backup/daily`, everything looks normal on first sight:

```
www:~ # ls /backup/daily
2011_week28  2012_week30  2012_week34  2012_week38  2012_week42  2012_week49
2012_week27  2012_week31  2012_week35  2012_week39  2012_week43  2012_week50
2012_week28  2012_week32  2012_week36  2012_week40  2012_week44  
2012_week29  2012_week33  2012_week37  2012_week41  2012_week48
```

Actually, I just now noticed the week45 - week47 directories are missing.

The `/etc/fstab` entry for the share looks like this:

```
//192.168.10.55/linux_backup  /backup     cifs       noauto,user=linux_backup,uid=backup,gid=users 0 0
```

But in the backup script, it's mounted like this:

```
mount -t cifs  //192.168.10.55/linux_backup /backup -o username=linux_backup,password=password,uid=backup,gid=users
```

And `mount` shows its properties like this:

> //192.168.10.55/linux_backup on /backup type cifs
>   (rw,relatime,sec=ntlm,unc=\192.168.10.55\linux_backup,username=linux_backup,uid=0,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=192.168.10.55,unix,posixpaths,serverino,acl,rsize=1048576,wsize=65536,actimeo=1)

For completeness sake, here's the backup script as well:

```
#!/bin/bash

backup_dir="/backup/daily/"
date=`date +%Y_week%V`
backup_path=${backup_dir}/$date/
rsync="/usr/bin/rsync -auv --no-o --no-g --delete"

#mount and create dir
echo "Backup started `date`"
mount -t cifs  //192.168.10.55/linux_backup /backup -o username=linux_backup,password=password,uid=backup,gid=users
mkdir -p $backup_path
chmod 700 $backup_path

#home dirs
home_src=/home/
home_dst=${backup_path}/home/
${rsync} $home_src $home_dst

#cleanup
umount /backup
echo "Backup ended `date`"
exit 0
```

After having written all this up, it seems to me there must have been something strange going on between week 44 and week 48, which has now mysteriously fixed itself?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this or the reason for the 'mysterious' fix?